# Including XML Comments in DataContract Serializer Metadata

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontract

is there some way of sending the summary info of properties in a DataContract?

e.g.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
  /// <summary>
  /// My Summary information
  /// </summary>
  [DataMember]
  public int MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

can this be available to the client that gets the datacontract? I doubt it, just hoping somebody knows something I don't, which is quite likely. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [WCFExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.  I haven't used it, but it sounds like it does exactly what you want:

> **Adding WSDL Documentation from Source Code XML Comments**
>
> This extension allows you to add WSDL
>   documentation (annotaiton) directly
>   from XML comments in your source file.
>   These comments will be published as
>   part of the WSDL and are available for
>   WSDL tools that know how to take
>   advantage of them (e.g. Apache Axis
>   wsdl2java and others). Release 2.0
>   also includes a client side WSDL
>   importer that will turn those WSDL
>   comments to XML comments in the
>   generated proxy code.

Comment: WCFExtrasPlus has moved to GitHub. Here: https://github.com/lamronby/wcfextrasplus

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the XML comments, then no, they cannot be sent. There is noplace within a WSDL in which they could be sent in such a way that a client could use them.