# WCF custom help page (with comments)

Tags: c#, wcf

how I can add comments to DataMembers in my DataContracts?

so in help page I want to see what all members in response or request means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including XML Comments in DataContract Serializer Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198911/including-xml-comments-in-datacontract-serializer-metadata)

Comment: I have REST service and it's not work

Comment: How do you imagine your comments of DataMembers? How it would look like for the developers who uses your REST web service?